# Select an interval date max date and min date

Tags: php, mysql

i want to select from a table date max and date min . using form

```
$datemax=$_POST['maxdate'];
$datemin=$_POST['mindate'];
    ("select * from demande inner join gestionnaire on gestionnaire.idgab = demande.idgab  where demande.idgab='$idgabsess' order by demande.dateincidnt")
```

i want to select from column dateincidnt where  ($datemax) ------> (datemin)

Comment: Please escape or cast the $_POST values before they're injected in the query otherwise you're subject to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MySQL` `between` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
```

In your code

```
select * from table where dateincidnt between $datemax and datemin
```

Comment: can you explain me that more

Answer (score 2):

Use the `BETWEEN` operator

```
$sql = "select * from demande
        inner join gestionnaire on gestionnaire.idgab = demande.idgab
        where demande.idgab='$idgabsess'
              and dateincidnt between $datemin and $datemax
        order by demande.dateincidnt";
```